# Serving next.js static assets from public folder after building time problems

Tags: nginx, next.js

I'm working on a nextjs application that should be deployed in a LAN, and the server is not connected to the internet. So the problem that I have is that in the `backoffice` I've got some forms to `add/update/delete` employees informations. There are also images profiles and QRCode that are generated for some reasons. I store those images inside `users_images` folder inside the `next.js public folder`. In development everything works just fine I can server those static files(images). But when I execute `next build` and run the application for production,only images in the `users_images` are build time are serverd but the news assets that are being created in the backoffice are not served and the server returns `404`.I've read in the nextjs docs and that is the expected behavior : [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

As the application will be deployed in an offline server, I cannot use services like `AWS s3` or services such as `cloudinary` for storing and retrieving images. Do you have any ideas about how to solve this problem to help me serve those files even after `build`?

I've also tried serving them with `nginx` and images are accessible but I get `505` while accessing pages. Here is my `nginx configuration`.

Next application listen on `port 3000`

```
server{
   listen 3000;
   root /path_to_apps_public_folder;
   location /{
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } 
}
```

Comment: How do you `run the application for production`, after run `next build`, you run `next start` or just deploy the built file into a static host?

Comment: As I'm using yarn I run it doing `yarn start`

Answer (score 4):

Now I know you run the Next.js server at production, not building the static files and run as a client-side rendering app.

Look at your nginx config, it only serves static files (public folder, _next folder), you should add a proxy_pass to your Next.js server to handle other request (page requests, api routes...)

I rarely use nginx's `root`, because I know Next.js only have two static folders: public's subfolders (usually "static", put at public/static), and `_next`

```
server{
   listen 3000;
   
    
   location ^~ /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/public/static/;
        sendfile           on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
    }

    location ^~ /_next/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/_next/;
        sendfile           on;
        sendfile_max_chunk 1m;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://<host_to_next_js>:<port>;
    }
}
```

You can search around for the example configuration of Nginx + Next.js (https://steveholgado.com/nginx-for-nextjs/#final-nginx-configuration)

Comment: After i've updated the configuration, nothing has changed.Still the files that were in the public directory at buil time are served,and for the rest i'm getting a `404`.

Comment: Could you provide your latest nginx configuration file by updating your question?